# Regular Dependency Property returning value even it hasn't been defined for a class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I define Dependency Property **for the A class**. However, I can query the value of that property in an instance of B. Why?

To illustrate, look a this code (WPF):

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Sample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var propDefinedForA = DependencyProperty.Register("SomeProperty", typeof(int), typeof(A), new PropertyMetadata(defaultValue: 10));

            var b = new B();        
            var value = b.GetValue(propDefinedForA);

        }
    }

    public class A: DependencyObject
    {
    }   

    public class B: DependencyObject
    {
    }  
}
```

After the execution of this code, the value is 10. Why is this even possible? I haven't defined the DP for the B class, but for A.

What's the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

From [Understanding WPF Dependency Property and Attached Property](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/helloworld/2010/06/25/understanding-wpf-dependency-property-and-attached-property/):

> **Dependency Property**
>
> This is WPF property system, even though this is a property, it is not
>   the same as regular property. The properties are not stored in an
>   internal field, but it is stored in an internal storage system that
>   stores per-instance value of the property.
>
> The dependency property is a public static read-only field that must
>   be registered first. After it has been registered, this static
>   property is used to get and set the value in the internal storage
>   system.
>
> **Attached Property**
>
> This is also dependency property. The internal storage system takes a
>   DependencyProperty as key to get and set value. Attached property
>   allows an object to to store a value using key that belongs to another
>   class.
>
> Imagine WPF property system is a property bag, and the property bag
>   can take any kind of values. In most cases, the key for this property
>   bag is defined in the class itself, but for attached property, the key
>   is defined in other class.

Basically using Attached Properties you can define properties for controls you don't access their internal state or you can't change their source code.